# How to embed an ID in Pixel 3a EXIF data?

Tags: metadata, cameraphones

My wife and I both use Pixel3a phones so we are not always sure which one took which photo.  Is it possible to embed some information into the exif data on one camera for use later as id. thanks

Comment: Please clarify: you said your and your wife both use the same model **phones** (plural), correct? Do you swap phones? Why is it that one person's phone doesn't contain only the photos that person took? Do you share online photo credentials?

Comment: The exif data should have some phone-specific info. Have you take a look?

Comment: ... phone-specific info... like serial number.

Answer (score 1):

@Ray Butterworth wrote

> I think the real question is how to configure each phone to add an identifying tag.

With [OpenCamera](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/net.sourceforge.opencamera) you can configure the copyright-exif marker that will be added to every photo

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool called `exiftool` ([link](http://exiftool.org/)) it has a command line interface that allows you to modify image tags and metadata. One particular tag you can use to distinguish between 2 devices could be the `copyright` tag or the `CopyrightNotice` tag, here is an example of what you could do:

```
exiftool -rights="Person 1" image_0.jpg
```

Or even the author meta tag:

```
exiftool -XMP-dc:Creator="Person 2" image_0.jpg
```

Here is [a list](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Image-ExifTool/lib/Image/ExifTool/TagNames.pod#EXIF-Tags) of most if not all EXIF tags among other tags that you can set using `exiftool`

Comment: I'm guessing that both phones automatically upload the photos to the same cloud account (e.g. Google Photos).  Once there, they are already shuffled together and it's too late to add EXIF tags.  ¶ I think the real question is how to configure each phone to add an identifying tag. ¶ I don't know about this one, but some devices can be configured to automatically add Copyright tags or to set a prefix for the filename.